# How to run a program within a C program and interact with it

Tags: c

I wanted to create a program that could open another program and interact with it. For exemple, would it be possible to create a C program that opens mysql.exe with its right parameters and "paste" or print the password required for it to run? If its too hard to do in C, is there any other language that could do it easier?

Comment: Modifying an executable is ill-advised.

Comment: By "make changes on it" I assume you mean giving input to the other program. The short answer then is yes, this is possible.

Comment: What you want to use is called a "pipe".

Comment: @FiddlingBits That was my first impression when I read the title, but after reading the body of the question, I think the OP is asking something completely different.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Probably so.

Comment: OP, could you provide an example of what you want to do? (I know you don't know _how_ to do it, which is why you asked the question, but just the pieces you know.) It's a little confusing from just the title and body.

Comment: Well, its basically it. By making changes i meant that the program i made could be able to interact by inputs with the other one that it will open. As in the mysql.exe exemple, by using its command-line version. But i think you guys are right, i should learn pipe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF youe are talking about command line programs, then you should look at pipes and how to use them from within C.

If we are talking about graphical/GUI programs: There is no standard way doing this, because it depends on the operating system and the GUI-Framework.

In Windows you can start a program, get its process Id, get the windows of the process and post messages to the window.

But for such tasks i would try to use some autmation language/frameworks.
Maybe have a look at `autoit`. 
Controlling other programs UI and inputs is exactly that it is made for

Comment: Thanks! I think this is it. I was referring to command line programs, but i was also curious about GUI programs.